# Jquery on click change image file extension

Tags: jquery, replace, click

I am using jQuery for this.
I want to change file extention of a image file on click. And want to change it back again on another click. and so on.

Here is what I have right now but it's not working. Not even working for first click. I think the replace syntax is not wight.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('img#featured').on( 'click', function() {
        $(this).attr( 'src', replace( '.jpg', '.gif' ) );
    });

});
```

And image code is this.

```
<img src="sample-image.jpg" id="featured" />
```

Comment: There's no function `replace()`. And even if there were, you're not giving it the original URL as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do exactly what you want it to do.

```
 $('img#featured').on('click', function() {
     var src = $(this).attr('src');
     if (src.indexOf(".jpg") > -1) {
         src = src.replace('.jpg','.gif' );
     } else {
         src = src.replace('.gif','.jpg' );
     }
     $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: I created a jsFiddle for you as well, http://jsfiddle.net/aezv7k4o/

If you open up the development console you will see the src change from jpg to gif and back.

Comment: Yes it's working and looks good. But what exactly are you checking with indexOf?

Comment: `src` is an attribute and should use `.attr()`.  `.prop()` is for true/false values (such as 'disabled').

Comment: Whether the `src` string contains the value `.jpg`.  `indexOf` returns the location in the string of the supplied value.  -1 is returned if the value is not in the string. So anything `>-1` the value is in the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('img#featured').on( 'click', function() {
  var $t=$(this), txt =$t.attr('src');
  if (txt.indexOf('.jpg')>-1) {
    txt=txt.replace('.jpg','.png');
  } else {
    txt=txt.replace('.png','.jpg');
  }
  $t.attr( 'src', txt );

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to `.attr()`. It receives the old value of the attribute as an argument, and must return the new value.

```
$('img#featured').on( 'click', function() {
    $(this).attr( 'src', function(i, oldsrc) {
        if (oldsrc.indexOf('.jpg') != -1) {
            return oldsrc.replace( '.jpg', '.gif' ) );
        } else {
            return oldsrc.replace( '.gif', '.jpg' ) );
        }
    });
});
```

You can use similar syntax with other methods for setting things on DOM element: `.html()`, `.text()`, `.val()`, `.prop`, and `.data()`. The first argument is the index of the current element in the collection (this might be useful if you're operating on multiple elements), the second argument is the old value being replaced.

Comment: It's working for first click but does not toggel extensions on future clicks.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that part of your question.